# UTC time for css

Tags: javascript, css, date, datetime, timezone

I have this script working it gives me the UTC time but it goes over 24!
example

sydney time 13 + (-11) = 2 | Los Angeles time 19 +(7) = 26

this 26 show be 2! because 24 is maximum

```
 var now = new Date();
 var utc = (now.getHours() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60));
```

Comment: I'm confused as to the relevance for CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
now.getUTCHours()
```

For reference see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, and shouldn't, calculate this. `getUTCHours` gets you UTC time.

That said, if you still want to do the calculation / make your life harder:

```js
var now = new Date();
var utc = (now.getHours() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)) % 24;
```

The `% 24` is necessary to account for situations (like you encountered) where the conversion yields a number outside 0-23.

Comment: The time zone offset isn't necessarily an even number of hours. Australian Central Standard Time is UTC+09:30, Chatham Islands is UTC+12:45, so the above may yield hours as a decimal value.

Comment: That is a very good point. Do you know if modulo in JS works on non-integers?